# PHP, array manipulation to get keys with all same name

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, codeigniter-2

I have this array posting to my controller:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 95
            [1] => 69
        )
)
```

I want:

```
Array(

    [id] => 95
    [id] => 69
)
```

As I am using CodeIgniter's $this->db->delete() function and it takes the array key value as the column for the WHERE clause. I have this code at the moment:

```
foreach($ids as $k => $v){

    $formatIds['id'] = $v;

}
```

Which just gives me one of the rows and not the rest.

I then tried:

```
foreach($ids as $k => $v){

    $formatIds['id'][] = $v;

}
```

But this gives me a MultiDimensional array...

Comment: Why do you _want_ a broken array? It makes no sense for two different values to have the same key. I think you should change your approach.

Comment: This is not possible, because it is logically senseless. It contradicts the basic idea of an associative array.

Comment: `Array(

    [0] => 95
    [1] => 69
)` is possible; but you can't have multiple array elements with the same key

Comment: ok so if I try using the first array i posted above in the CodeIgniter function to delete rows it tries something like this in the query DELETE FROM table WHERE 0 = 95, DELETE FROM table WHERE 1 = 69.... So how can I achieve what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is "not possible": array keys must always be unique.

The answer to what you're trying to do is to use `where_in()`:

```
$names = array(95,69);
$this->db->where_in('id', $names);
$this->db->delete('mytable');
```